# Is Open layer tile loading site acetate.geoiq.com down?

Tags: drupal, openlayers

Is Open layer tile loading site **acetate.geoiq.com** down? It was working for some years and suddenly the site is showing timeout error. Can anybody please help. Is there any information about the site **acetate.geoiq.com**?

Answer (score 1):

Don't have actual information one way or the other, but you're not alone: I have several leaflet-based maps that use Acetate tiles, and they are no longer working.